# What does the phrase "unwanted advances" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The term ‘Bobbitised' came into currency after a young US woman, Lorena Bobbitt, cut off her husband's genitals in 1993 to ward off **unwanted advances**.

Comment: Google **unwanted advances meaning** to find the answer. (Don't just google **unwanted advances** as it is the title of a book!)

Comment: 'unwanted advances' is a phrase, not a word.

Answer (score 1):

It means that Lorena's husband was trying to initiate sexual activity which Lorena did not want.

It seems idiomatic now, as I'm not sure I've ever heard the phrase used to describe anything other than sexual advances even though the word *sexual* is specifically not used in the expression.

Comment: There are situations where one person may interpret another's actions as an unwanted advance, even when there is not overt sexual implication. For example, one person (especially a man) asking another (especially a woman) in a cafe **May I share your table?** - or sitting beside someone in a bus when there are vacant seats available.

Comment: @RonaldSole I agree that such situations exist, but while there is nothing definitionally wrong about describing one as an "unwanted advance" I don't think I've ever heard the phrase used that way. Is that the actual expression you would use to describe such an event?

Comment: If I were 50 years younger and female, I might well. Given my age and balding pate I doubt it.

Comment: @RonaldSole Have you heard that expression used to describe any situation which lacked any sexual component? That's the crux of my question above-- you're not wrong about parsing and defining each word of the sentence, I just haven't encountered alternative meanings in actual use.